# Docker Desktop - The network name cannot be found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I have docker desktop installed on my machine. I also configured container with image. its running. but when I quit docker desktop (when I don't require) and open again. I am getting below error every time -

> Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException: {"message":"2 errors
> occurred:\n\t* provisioning docker WSL distros: deploying
> "docker-desktop": importing WSL distro "docker-desktop": deploying
> WSL distro "docker-desktop" ("C:\\Program
> Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\wsl\\wsl-bootstrap.tar"
> -\u003e "C:\\Users\\testuser\\AppData\\Local\\Docker\\wsl\\distro"):
> exit status 0xffffffff\n\t* checking if isocache exists: CreateFile
> \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\isocache\: The network name cannot be
> found.\n\n"}

I then have to do - reset to defaults. it would lead to delete my container and I had to restart computer and again configure container. what I am missing?

Comment: Deleting and recreating a container should be pretty routine; you'll need to do it whenever the application in the container changes, or if you need to change any of a range of Docker-level configuration options.  Is it a problem to need to do this?

Comment: @DavidMaze Why should I delete container if there is no change? can't I stop container and shut down PC. and start PC and start container? I have to do this way. I don't want to delete container every time. but here, docker failed to start next time when I open  and above mentioned error comes.

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process, so when you rebooted you caused the container to stop.  You could probably run a new process in a stopped container (which is what `docker start` does) but it won't necessarily be a clean environment.  If `docker rm` addresses the problem, I'd consider that so routine as to be an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked -

1. Click on show hidden icons.
2. Click on docker desktop icon
3. Troubleshoot
4. Reset to factory defaults.
   let me add I had the luxury of rebuilding my containers.